# In MySQL's client\server protocol, how to set the format of row data packet of as binary?

Tags: mysql

According to MySQL internal manual, the default format of row data packet that server respond to client's command(e.g. a sql select statement) is character. However, the manual also mentions the packet could be in binary form. I'd like to know how to set the format of row data packet of as binary?
[The description of row data packet:binary in MySQL internal manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpmE0.png)

Comment: What is you real goal?

Comment: To improve efficiency by skipping the process that server transfers any non-character column into character before sending it.